# What is error "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"?

Tags: python

I was working on a project that needed numpy. I used pip install numpy and got the message it is already installed. After completing that code and when I was running a different code I get the following error which did not happen before. I am using Python 3.6. Same versions before and after the issue.

Client code :

```
import requests
#import json
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, array_to_img, load_img
from keras.preprocessing import image

flowers = 'c:/flower_photos/daisy/107592979_aaa9cdfe78_m.jpg'
#for x in flowers:
image1 = img_to_array(image.load_img(flowers, target_size=(128,128))) / 255
payload = {
      "instances": [{"image":image1.tolist()},
]
}
print("sending request...")
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/flowers/versions/1:predict', json=payload)
#r = requests.get('http://localhost:8051/v1/models/modelflowers/versions/1/metadata')
print(r.content)
```

I get the following error :

```
C:\flowers_old>client.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-02-10 19:15:06.355011: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

I uninstalled both TF and numpy and put them back. Still the same error.
Any help ?

Thanks,
Pubudu

Comment: Looks like you got a version of numpy that doesn't have support for 16bit floats complied in, but tf wants it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is found with numpy 1.16.1. When downgraded it to numpy 1.15.4, it's working fine.
So the suggestion is to create a conda environment, activate it and do the necessary installations.

Follow the steps below.

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.6 numpy=1.15.4
```

'my_env' is the conda environment name.

Activate the environment

```
activate my_env
```

Install the necessary packages: For eg.

```
conda install -c anaconda requests
```

Similarly you can install other packages like keras, tensorflow etc. as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.